# Exception of using freed objects in rapid painting cycles

Tags: delphi, exception, free, paint

**Summarization:**
For a Delphi function/procedure, if an instance of a class is passed through as an argument, another reference (besides the original reference) is created on temporary calling stack to point to that instance and is used locally. Thus, be careful:

(1) If the function/procedure only wants to change the content/fields/properties of that instance, no var prefix is needed;

(2) If the function/procedure probably wants to re-assign the reference to a new instance, use var prefix, or it is the temporary reference that gets re-assigned.

(3) Note, if the function/procedure re-assigns the reference and the var prefix is not used, the outcome is probably right, which is even worse, because eventually the code will break some day.

=======================================
**The situation is:**
It is a small application. The TMolForm is a MDIChild Form, and every TMolForm contains a TMolScene, which descends from TPaintBox. The TMolScene draws the TMol. In the painting procedure of TMolScene, TMolScene calls TMol.Rescale if TMolScene is resized. Then TMolScene calls TMol.TransformCoordinates to build up coordinates for the subsequent rendering.

**The problem is:**
Now, in TMol.Rescale, I reset the matrices passed through by the caller, TMolScene. However, I meet exceptions which I cannot think of the reason.

(1) Specifically, if I have **multiple** TMolForm, and **rapidly** do resizing, mouse dragging (which is molecule rotating), switching between TMolForm, in less than 5 minutes, suddenly the matrices (supposedly already resetted in TMol.Rescale) passed into TMol.TransformCoordinates are nil or contain nil content.

(2) If I enable FastMM4 and its FullDebugMode, and repeat the above mouse movements, I can get "TMol.Rescale attempts to free a freed object". It seems TMol.Rescale is called again when the last call (or the last paint cycle) is not finished. I mean, I didn't make any attempts involving multi-threading, how possibly could TMol.Rescale be call the second time when the last call does not return yet?
I am completely lost. Could you help to comment on any possible reasons?

(3) If I remove the resetting of matrices out of TMol.Rescale and into its caller, TMolScene.OnScenePaint, the exceptions seem not to happen, at least not in 5 minutes. (I did not **rapidly** abusing the mouse longer than 5 minutes. Perhaps there is other better way of testing.) I have no clue why this works and why the above crashes **sometimes**.

(4) If I only have one TMolform, the above exceptions seem not to happen, at least not in 5 minutes.

I must admit that I made up the following minimized code in order to catch the exceptions. However, although the execution procedure should mirror the real situation, the exceptions **don't** occur. If you would like to see the real code I am willing to send to you through email or something else. It is hobby and **not** well written, though, sorry.

Any suggestions, either on the exceptions, or on bad coding habits, are really appreciated.

```
        unit uMolForm;

        interface

        uses
          Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
          ExtCtrls, Dialogs;

        type
          TVec = class;
          TMat = class;
          TMol = class;
          TMolScene = class;
          TMolForm = class;

          TVec = class
          public
            X, Y, Z: Extended;
            constructor Create; overload;
            constructor Create(aX, aY, aZ: Extended); overload;
          end;

          TMat = class
          private
            FX, FY, FZ, FT: TVec;
          public
            property X: TVec read FX;
            property Y: TVec read FY;
            property Z: TVec read FZ;
            constructor Create;
            destructor Destroy; override;
            function ToUnit: TMat;
          end;

          TMol = class
          public
            constructor Create;
            destructor Destroy; override;
            procedure Rescale(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
              aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
            procedure TransformCoordinates(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
              aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
          end;

          TMolScene = class(TPaintBox)
          private
            FBbWidth, FBbHeight: Integer;
            FRotationMat, FTranslationMat, FScalingMat: TMat;
            FMol: TMol;
            procedure OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
            procedure OnSceneMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
              Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
            procedure OnSceneMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
              Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
            procedure OnSceneMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
              X, Y: Integer);
          public
            constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
            destructor Destroy; override;
          end;

          TMolForm = class(TForm)
            procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
            procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
          private
            { Private declarations }
            FMolScene: TMolScene;
          public
            { Public declarations }
          end;

        implementation

        {$R *.dfm}

        { TVec }

        constructor TVec.Create;
        begin
          inherited;

          X := 0;
          Y := 0;
          Z := 0;
        end;

        constructor TVec.Create(aX, aY, aZ: Extended);
        begin
          inherited Create;

          X := aX;
          Y := aY;
          Z := aZ;
        end;

        { TMat }

        constructor TMat.Create;
        begin
          inherited;

          ToUnit;
        end;

        destructor TMat.Destroy;
        begin
          FreeAndNil(FX);
          FreeAndNil(FY);
          FreeAndNil(FZ);
          FreeAndNil(FT);

          inherited;
        end;

        function TMat.ToUnit: TMat;
        begin
          FreeAndNil(FX);
          FreeAndNil(FY);
          FreeAndNil(FZ);
          FreeAndNil(FT);

          FX := TVec.Create(1, 0, 0);
          FY := TVec.Create(0, 1, 0);
          FZ := TVec.Create(0, 0, 1);
          FT := TVec.Create;

          Result := Self;
        end;

        { TMol }

        constructor TMol.Create;
        begin
          inherited;

        end;

        destructor TMol.Destroy;
        begin

          inherited;
        end;

        procedure TMol.Rescale(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
          aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
        begin

          FreeAndNil(aRotationMatUser);
          FreeAndNil(aTranslationMatUser);
          FreeAndNil(aScalingMatUser);

          aRotationMatUser := TMat.Create;
          aTranslationMatUser := TMat.Create;
          aScalingMatUser := TMat.Create;
        end;

        procedure TMol.TransformCoordinates(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
          aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
        begin

          if (aRotationMatUser.X = nil) or (aRotationMatUser.Y = nil) or
            (aRotationMatUser.Z = nil) or (aTranslationMatUser.X = nil) or
            (aTranslationMatUser.Y = nil) or (aTranslationMatUser.Z = nil) or
            (aScalingMatUser.X = nil) or (aScalingMatUser.Y = nil) or
            (aScalingMatUser.Z = nil) then
          begin
            raise Exception.Create('what happened?!');
          end;
        end;

        { TMolScene }

        constructor TMolScene.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
        begin
          inherited;

          FRotationMat := TMat.Create;
          FTranslationMat := TMat.Create;
          FScalingMat := TMat.Create;
          FMol := TMol.Create;

          Self.OnPaint := Self.OnScenePaint;
          Self.OnMouseDown := Self.OnSceneMouseDown;
          Self.OnMouseUp := Self.OnSceneMouseUp;
          Self.OnMouseMove := Self.OnSceneMouseMove;
        end;

        destructor TMolScene.Destroy;
        begin
          FreeAndNil(FRotationMat);
          FreeAndNil(FTranslationMat);
          FreeAndNil(FScalingMat);
          FreeAndNil(FMol);

          inherited;
        end;

        procedure TMolScene.OnScenePaint(Sender: TObject);
        begin
          if (FBbWidth <> Self.ClientWidth) or (FBbHeight <> Self.ClientHeight) then
          begin
            FBbWidth := Self.ClientWidth;
            FBbHeight := Self.ClientHeight;
            FMol.Rescale(FBbWidth, FBbHeight, FRotationMat, FTranslationMat,
              FScalingMat);
          end;

          FMol.TransformCoordinates(FBbWidth, FBbHeight, FRotationMat, FTranslationMat,
            FScalingMat);
        end;

        procedure TMolScene.OnSceneMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
          Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        begin
          Self.Repaint;
        end;

        procedure TMolScene.OnSceneMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
          Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        begin
          Self.Repaint;
        end;

        procedure TMolScene.OnSceneMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
          Y: Integer);
        begin
          Self.Repaint;
        end;

        { TMolForm }

        procedure TMolForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        begin
          FMolScene := TMolScene.Create(Self);
          FMolScene.Parent := Self;
          FMolScene.Align := alClient;
        end;

        procedure TMolForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        begin
          Action := caFree;
        end;

        end.
```

Comment: If you are bothered about performance you'd be better off using double precision than extended

Comment: @David: Thank you for your comment! Indeed I am! Then I should learn from the best practices.

Comment: What's more, for real performance you don't want TVec as a class. Much better is a record. You get stack allocation and the opportunity to use operator overloading.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I agree performance can benefit from using record and stack allocation. However, in current codes, TVec has some procedures such as Add/Subtract/Scale/Len and so forth. In Delphi 7, the version which Lazarus tries to keep compatibility to, it seems I cannot define function/procedure for record type. Operator overloading is also a quite new feature. Keeping the codes compatible with Lazarus makes it possible to compile for Mac. (I use your full user name because StackOverflow says it can then send message to the message recipient.)

Comment: @Xichen OK, I had not realised you were trying to do cross-platform. You could consider using `object` - don't know if Lazarus supports that. It's an old Turbo Pascal construct. It's essentially equivalent to a record with methods. The thing about stack allocation for a 3 vector is not just that the code runs faster, but it's generally preferable to have value type semantics rather than reference semantics for code working on such types. Well, that's my own personal opinion!

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you very much for your comment! I totally agree that TVec should be of value type because it means a simple value. Nonetheless, perhaps it is better that I first get everything run smoothly before starting refactoring such as switching from class to object. (I remember that AggPas makes heavily use of object and that the author of AggPas is convinced that using object makes AggPas faster than not.)

Comment: @xichen yes you are right. Get it working. Then refactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code

```
    procedure TMol.Rescale(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
      aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
    begin

      FreeAndNil(aRotationMatUser);
      FreeAndNil(aTranslationMatUser);
      FreeAndNil(aScalingMatUser);

      aRotationMatUser := TMat.Create;
      aTranslationMatUser := TMat.Create;
      aScalingMatUser := TMat.Create;
    end;
```

is an error. You should pass `aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser` parameters by reference:

```
    procedure TMol.Rescale(aBbWidth, aBbHeight: Integer;
      **var** aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser: TMat);
```

---

You should use **var** to pass the arguments in the above procedure because without it

- FreeAndNil 'nilles' the temporary
  stack variables, and it makes no
  sense;
- constructor calls assign
  values to the temporary stack
  variables, with resulting memory
  leaks.

The question why the erroneous code sometimes work right (and probably does not even cause memory leaks) is a different story.

---

**One more edit**

As you already mentioned a Delphi object is a reference. So you need not use `var` to change the object. But your procedure is different - it changes the references themselves, not only the data pointed by these references, so you should pass these references (`aRotationMatUser, aTranslationMatUser, aScalingMatUser`) by reference. That is why you need `var`.

Comment: @Serg: Thank you for your help! Then I don't understand why it works when I only open one TMolForm? The exceptions occur quite randomly. Furthermore, since TMat is class, isn't "by reference" already the way to pass through arguments?

Comment: Delphi class is a reference, but you need 'reference to reference' in the above procedure

Comment: @Serg: Thank you for your comment! Could you suggest any material that I could learn about that term? Furthermore, I still don't know why it only happen randomly. Nonetheless, I just added var keyword and will try another few minutes and let you know.

Comment: @Serg: Adding var to the argument list eliminates the exceptions! Thank you very much! I am somehow still lost about (1) why in the real codes exceptions are raised only randomly (2) the above demo codes do not raise exceptions? Also, could you help to comment the best practice of using var prefix for an argument? I mean, I seem to remember a code sample where a tstringlist is passed through to be modified but without var prefix.

Comment: @Serg: Oh! You have explained in your answer! Thank you! That different story, could you please share some of your point of view? :)

Comment: @Serg: By the way, I found the link that [tstrings passed through without var prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894983/why-use-exception-handling-in-apparently-safe-code/1895629#1895629). Nick's answer passed through a TStrings instance to be modified but without var prefix. Could you help to comment why it is safe in that situation? Also, could you help to comment what is the best practice to use the var prefix?

Comment: @Serg: I see! Thank you very much for your kind help and knowledgeable comments!!